# (Re)Deploy .NET logic onto multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-services

Preamble: Multiple (5+) servers runs same workers. Workers listen RabbitMQ queie for task and execute it.
Problem: Workers logic changes (up to 2-3 times per day), need a robust way to re-deploy updated workers onto multiple servers.

I realize such distributed computing environment can be written from scratch (poll something for updates, download assembly and run it into separate AppDomain) but I'm trying to find some framework first...

Comment: which kind of app are your workers? Windows services? Web apps? Or what?

Comment: At current pre-beta stage workers are just plain old console applications. Can repackage them as Windows Service any time...  Actually workers are multi-threaded web crawlers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a pre-beta stage I would go with some powershell script, which can easily poll, download and start/stop apps or services without the need of running in separated AppDomain (trust me, this wouldn't be trivial at all). These scripts can also easily scheduled with the Windows task scheduler (you can also script the schedule task creation...).

In case you still want to try a ready made solution, I would take a look at:

1. [Octopus](https://octopusdeploy.com/), which is .Net native, but not free
2. [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet) or [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/), that are two of the leaders in deploy automation and both have free versions
3. [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) that is a younger (and with still limited Windows support) product but that I consider really interesting

UPDATE

If you already have it, [TFS](http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/manage-your-release-vs) maybe another possibility. I'm not sure if it can deploy windows services, but I would surprised if not.